# SQL Server Transaction Log Truncating/Shrinking

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have seen some stored procedures that wrap everything in a transaction.

```
begin transaction
    update
        table
    set
        column c = (column a * column b)
commit
```

Is this the right way to go about managing the transaction log?  I've tried this with some stored procedures but it looks like the log just gets out of hand.  What's the best way to manage the transaction log when running a stored procedure that has multiple update/insert/alter statements in it?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A SQL transaction is logged regardless if the query is implicitly wrapped in a transaction statement or recovery model. Depending on the recovery model the transaction will either remain in the log (full recovery mode) or be truncated (simple recovery mode). Regardless of the mode truncating the log does not shrink the file size.

Managing the log is not something that is typically handled in SQL queries within you application, rather a DBA task.

Transactions are stored to allow for recovery in the case of failure. Where you can step through transactions since your last backup to recreate the data at that point in time. Simple recovery mode does not allow this as the transaction is truncated immediately upon successful execution (COMMIT).

The log is typically truncated and shrunk upon backup. You can create SQL maintenance jobs to manage this.

Answer (score 2):

The log is not directly related to how many explicit `TRANSACTION`s you have in your query.  [It's related to your recovery model.](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dba/Database_Recovery_Models_in_SQL_Server_p1.aspx) The explicit `TRANSACTION` statements just use the log to rollback or commit upon request.

Also FYI your code would throw an error, since you have a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` without a `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`.

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed that I typed 'end' instead of 'commit'.

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to wrap this in a transaction.  It is running one statement so it will either succeed or fail.

If you were updating a second table and needed both to succeed to keep the data consistent then you might want to consider this approach.

However.. The size of the transaction log file will grow until it is backed up.  If your database is small you may wish to set the database recovery option to simple and just back up your whole database every night, this will also truncate the transaction log file.

Comment: Except setting the recovery to simple means you may lose data in a failure. Better for most applications to start backing up the transaction log instead. We do it every 15 minutes because we can't afford as a company to lose more data than that.

Comment: @divided, just to make it clear, backing up the database does NOT backup the transaction log, you need a separate transaction log backup.

Comment: You are right of course. I was going to go on and explain but was feeling the pressure of faster typists. Dustin's answer above is probably the most complete which is why I voted it up. However not all developers have the luxury of DBAs to manage their databases